# Meaning of WebSql query

Tags: sql, indexeddb, web-sql

I'm working on port code from WebSQL to IndexedDb. I'm stuck in the following query,

```
SELECT ad.* FROM AdminUserDetails as ad inner join CustomerDetails pd on 
pd.CaseManagerId=ad.AdminUserId or pd.CareCoordinatorId=ad.AdminUserId WHERE  
pd.CustomerNo='" + CustomerNo "'"
```

I'm not able to understand the complete above query and how do I convert the above code into IndexedDb.

Comment: It's mobile app browser-based. Anyways thanks, your thought will help me in the future. In the application, we do not store any data permanently local. When users log out all data will be deleted from the database.

Comment: The other major difference is that WebSQL is relational and IndexedDB is a NoSQL key-value store; I'm not sure it will support relational algebra (aka "joins").

Comment: IndexedDB persists data across sessions @TheImpaler

Comment: @Josh I stand corrected.